# Why doesn't my exception filter catch?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

This is on ASP.NET MVC 4.5. I am trying to get a basic exception filter to work. I keep getting `An exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in Filters.dll but was not handled in user code` but I think it is setup to handle that exception:

`Home/RangeTest/50`

**RangeExceptionAttribute.cs**

```
public class RangeExceptionAttribute : FilterAttribute, IExceptionFilter {
    public void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        if (!filterContext.ExceptionHandled && filterContext.Exception is ArgumentOutOfRangeException)
        {
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("~/Content/RangeErrorPage.html");
            filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

**HomeController.cs**

```
    [RangeException]
    public string RangeTest(int id)
    {
        if (id > 100)
            return String.Format("The id value is: {0}", id);
        else
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("id", id, "");
    }
```

Someone suggested I register the filter but in the book I am following they never have to register anything. But still I've tried to register by doing these:

```
// FilterConfig.cs        
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
{
    filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
    filters.Add(new RangeExceptionAttribute());
}



// Global.asax.cs
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        GlobalFilters.Filters.Add(new Filters.Infrastructure.RangeExceptionAttribute());

        WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }
}
```

Comment: The exception may have been wrapped up inside another exception first (such as `HttpException`).  Have you looked into the `InnerException` of the exception your filter picks up?

Comment: I think it is specifically an ArgumentOutOfRange Exception with no inner Exception. I could be looking at it wrong though. Here is a screenshot http://tinypic.com/r/a352o/8

Comment: What I mean was that by the time MVC can "see" the exception, it might not be an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` anymore.  If you put a breakpoint in the debugger on the first line of your filter does it even get hit?

Comment: ah sorry, no. it never goes in the filter at all (which I have observed by putting a breakpoint on the first line of the OnException method of the filter).

Comment: Wait, it actually IS working. But it triggers the unhandled exception dialog before the filter runs.

Comment: Have you got your IDE's exception handling setup in such a way that unhandled exceptions always cause the debugger to invoke? If you press continue in the unhandled exception dialog does it then flow through to your filter?

Comment: Yep, that is exactly what it does. If you press continue it goes on through to the OnException method of the filter and hits the breakpoint.

Comment: And after that are you getting the behaviour you want?

Comment: Correct, it is a false alarm. I've never seen Visual Studio show the unhandled exception dialog before the exception handler has a chance to run. So it's confusing when debugging but I think would work fine in production.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is it was breaking before the exception could be handled. The exception would have actually been handled fine but because I saw the unhandled exception dialog I kept stopping the program instead of pressing continue (at which point my exception filter does handle the error).

You can make the problem go away by unchecking this box:

[image]